# m2eclipse on windows with Mercurial does not allow hg to be used on the "Check out Maven Projects from SCM" wizard

Tags: mercurial, m2eclipse

I followed the answer from this posting:
[How to use Mercurial, Maven and Eclipse together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676267/how-to-use-mercurial-maven-and-eclipse-together)

But the "Check out Maven Projects from SCM" still does not allow me to use Mercurial SCM.

The only option I get is "svn" in the dropdown, and even if I ignore the drop down and enter in "scm:hg:http://*myMercurialRepoURL*"

I'm using:

1. Eclipse 3.6.1
2. m2eclipse 0.12 from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
3. "Maven SCM handler for Subclipse" 0.12.0 from m2eclipse extra's site (sorry, I would give the URL, but my new account doesn't have enough rep)
4. MercurialEclipse 1.8.1 from http://cbes.javaforge.com/update

And I've uninstalled, and reinstall those plugins in that order.

I'm able to use Maven in projects, and use Mercurial separately in Eclipse - it's just this one Wizard that seems to be broken, which leads me to believe that if I try to Materialize an Artifact from a Mercurial repo that it will also fail.

Has anyone had any luck with this Wizard? Perhaps on earlier versions? Is this a new bug?

Thanks

Comment: We use 'Import/Mercurial Clone existing local or remote Mercurial repository' and works also with maven projects.

Comment: I have the same problem. Already 3 days trying to find a scm connector for the mercurial.
I tried on eclipse3.6(Helios) and eclipse3.7(Indigo).
I tried different versions of maven plugin.
On m2eclipse Extras Update Site( http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras) only one connector for svn. If anyone has solved this problem please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

As far my search went, I didn't get to find a suitable connector for mercurial and m2eclipse (in terms of only using IDE). However, I did an experiment wherein I cloned a copy of the source from outside the IDE. (via TortoiseHg specifically)

Afterwards, assuming you have already m2e installed in Eclipse:
Go to File > import > maven > existing maven projects, then select the folder where you've originally pulled/cloned your source code.

I believe by doing so, you'll see the m2e commands in the project's context menu (via run as), and effective use mercurial commands. (via team context menu)

At least for now, this is better not using m2e and mercurial at the same time.

If anyone has a more streamlined approach, I'm also curious. :D

Comment: It [appears](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/389/integration-with-m2e), that integration with m2e is major feature for MercurialEclipse 2.1.x